# Can wp_insert_post_data filter be used to save custom field data?

Tags: custom-field, wp-insert-post, save-post

I have custom field data that I would like to modify on its way to the database.

wp_insert_post_data filter seems to be the closest thing I can find to achieving this. I dumped the $data and $postarr values but I don't see how I can access my custom field data as those fields aren't in the dump.

Can wp_insert_post_data be used to save custom field data, and if not, what is the preferred filter / practice?

EDIT: additional detail:

I have a front end form that asks for a user's company website address. If the user simply types in 'example.com' then the target for that website in his post defaults to mywebsite.com/example.com instead of opening up example.com.

If http:// is not part of the text they enter, then I want to add that to it right before it saves. There is javascript to help with validation, but those who have it turned off get by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the raw `$_POST` data from the `wp_insert_post_data` filter, but there are probably better ways to intercept that data.

- [`save_post` or similar hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2960) would probably work
- As you are dealing with post_meta, [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) uses
  [`update_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_metadata) which provides the `update_{$meta_type}_meta`
  and `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` filters. Those may be the best for
  you but your question is shy on detail so I can't be sure.

Based on the edit, use the `update_{$meta_type}_meta` filter. Your question is still light on detail but the following filter should dump all of the data so you can at least see what you are dealing with:

```
add_filter(
  'update_post_meta',
  function($meta_type,$object_id,$meta_key,$meta_value,$prev_value) {
    var_dump($meta_type,$object_id,$meta_key,$meta_value,$prev_value);
    die;
  },
  10,5
);
```

Note: that ***will break your site*** but not permanently. It is purely for debugging/development. It is just to give you a glance at the data that comes through the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added a bit more detail that helps clarify what I'm doing.

Comment: the save_post was just what I was looking for. I was able to get the meta fields for my post @ $post->ID and then manipulate them however, and then use update_post_meta in the callback of the save_post action to do just what I wanted. Thanks for the direction!